# WP-API custom post types, how do I use?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest, request

I try to use this [restAPI](http://wp-api.org/#posts) plugin to get custom created posts but somehow, maybe I missunderstood the API docs, but this returns all my available posts.

So I call

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?type=[my_custom_post_type]
```

returns all available

giving wrong post type

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?type=[my_hfjhfjh]
```

returns the same!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Post Types are not anymore directly accessible from v2 so  it needs to be set `"show_in_rest" => true` when registering a custom post type or taxonomy.